# How to run two functions asynchronously in setInterval?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have these two functions that take one argument each and which runs after every 2 seconds on a web page.

```
setInterval(() => {
requestCall_1(api1);
requestCall_2(api2);
}, 2000);
```

which is what I wanted and it works fine this way. But think it would be better if I could run these two functions asynchronously instead of this synchronous behavior. I am not very familiar with javascript asynchronous concepts. So can someone provide a basic solution to this with a bit explanation?

Comment: Where exactly do you see "synchronous behaviour"? Aren't these `requestCall` functions already asynchronous? I suppose you could set up two independent `setInterval`, one for each (but if these calls are blocking, that would not really help, because you have only one thread of execution, so the second one would wait for the first one to complete either way --- and if they are non-blocking, you might just put them into the same interval).

Comment: They are being run asynchronously.

Comment: @Thilo Aren't these "requestCall" functions running in a order where the second function is waiting until the first one finishes it's work. Is that not synchronous behavior ? Sorry if i am mistaken but i am new to this field.

Comment: @devil_coder can you show the function declarations or an idea about them for these functions?

Comment: I get it now.Yes these functions are async after all.Cause in the both function declarations i am just fetching some data from an api and calling the functions in seinterval . As these functions are aleardy being  run asynchronously in their declarations so i don't need to do any async function again in the setinterval method. I actually thought that i have to put them in async function again as they are being called orderly one after another.But since its already being done on declaration i dont need to do it again.Thats it guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function when you declared those 2 function

```
async function requestCall_1(api1) {
    // your code
}

async function requestCall_2(api2) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: And what difference does that make?